# Anyway to improve this given shell script which keeps testing a website using curl command?

Tags: bash, scripting

Here's the script which keeps testing given website and email via Mutt when it fails, using `curl` command, once it reduces failing emails from the version which uses `ping` command instead.

Would there be any way to improve it?

As follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    date > /tmp/sdown.txt
    if curl -fI "given.website.com" 1>& /dev/null ;
    then
        sleep 1
        :
    else
        mutt -s "Website Down!!!" user@email.com < /tmp/sdown.txt
        sleep 10
    fi
done
```

Comment: Improve in what way? Speed? Readability? Reliability?

Comment: Might be reliability?

Comment: You are not checking the actual `curl` output. You might want to check that string or something is in there, so you get also alerted on defacement.

Comment: Might give curl the `--max-time` parameter so that curl doesn't run forever if your server is broken and not writing anything after accepting the connection. And when the web site is down, sending one email every 10 seconds is probably going to annoy the email recipient. Instead, send no more emails until the web site comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `:` is not needed after `sleep 1`.

Second, if you don't need the temp file for other reasons, you could simply use `date` where it's needed. So this script can be reduced so:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    if curl -fI "given.website.com" 1>& /dev/null; then
        sleep 1
    else
        date | mutt -s "Website Down!!!" user@email.com
        sleep 10
    fi
done
```